# Инсталлятор Windows10 не видит "вшитого" ключа

Tags: windows-10, update

Был куплен ноутбук с установленной Windows 8. Без проблем обновил до Windows 8.1. Когда вышел Window 10, долго ждал когда сам предложит обновиться. Так и не дождался. Скачал установщик на флешку  с сайта Microsoft. Запускаю установку, а она запрашивает ключ. Ввожу тот, который от Windows 8, а он не подходит.

 *Как решить эту проблему?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет вшитого ключа для Windows 10. Он выдаётся только при обновлении. Нужно обновиться, а не установить с установщика. Поэтому нужно переустановить 8ку, установить все обновления и вместе с ними должно прийти обновление до 10ки (скорей всего на старой 8ке чо-то сломалось и обновление не пришло). Удобный установщик правильной версии 8ки можно скачать у Microsoft: http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Comment: Откатил на заводское состояние, до Win8. С сайта Mircosoft скачал "обновлялку" до Win10. Вот уже 33%. Ключ не спрашивает.

Comment: @MaximK так и должно быть - в биосе был вшит ключ 8ки, поэтому его не спрашивает. А для 10ки ключ только что был выдан и вшит в биос, или будет выдан при установке